Is there a method to update C# version in Visual Studio to 12.0 when using the .NET framework?
I have a project and need to create an array of textboxes and list boxes which apparently is supported in C# 7.3 and I need C# 12.0, however reading online documentation I cannot use C# 12.0 in .NET framework and now I've hit a roadblock.
This is the error I get:


Use ... = new TextBox[] { gearRatio, etc };

Use a collection/array initializer instead:
TextBox[] ARR_GearBoxEntryBoxes = { TXTBOX_GearRatio1, TXTBOX_GearRatio2 };


The [ ... ] syntax is a collection expression introduced in C# 12. It can be used everywhere in the code where an expression is required.
ProcessNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

List<int> GetNumbers()
{
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

In contrast, the { ... } syntax is a collection initializer introduced in C# 3.0 and it can only be used when initializing a collection as part of a declaration.
var names = new List<string> { "Simon", "Mary", "Sue" };
int[] numbers = { 2, 6, 8 }; // The new keyword can be dropped for arrays only.

See also:

Collection expressions - C# language reference
Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)


To use newer C# versions in older Framework versions just set <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> in a property group in *.csproj. You also need a newer version of Visual Studio or a comparable IDE.
See also:

Configure C# language version


